# jquery: json Request Output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Why my JSON value is not parsed into an Object?

This is my **jquery** part

```
$.ajax({
                url:'url.php',
                type:'post',
                data:{'players':playersDone, 'userID':userID, 'gameVariant':gameVariant, 'gameWeek':gameWeek,},
                success: function (res) {                        
                    console.log(res);
                    alert(res);
                    alert(res.idOfLastRow);
                    window.location.href = " summary.php?idOfLastEntry='"+res.idOfLastRow+"' ";
                }
            });
```

and my **php** looks like this:

```
...
...
      '".$_POST['players']['fw3']."',
      ".$_POST['players']['sub']."',
      '',
      '');";

    mysqli_query($connection, $queryInsertFinishedDraft);
    $_POST['players']['idOfLastRow'] = $connection->insert_id;
```

**JSON Data**

When I output my received data from the response in an alert, it looks like this

```
{"df1":"952","idOfLastRow":77}
```

However when I try to access one of the fields, I get *undefined*:

`alert(res.idOfLastRow)` is "undefined"

Comment: Wrong response content-type. Before you print the json, send the correct content-type. `header("Content-Type: application/json");`

Comment: thats it!!! THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 0):

in your ajax call you need to add datatype json

```
            url:'url.php',
            type:'post',
            dataType: 'json',   <---
            data:{'players':playersDone, 'userID':userID, 'gameVariant':gameVariant, 'gameWeek':gameWeek,},
            success: function (res) {
```

Comment: sorry but this wasnt the solution :(
SOlution was, i forgot to add a header! like header("Content-Type: application/json");

Answer (score 0):

You can either choose to return the correct content-type in PHP and let jquery do the magic:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

or parse the string yourself:

```
JSON.parse(res);
```